# Login & fetching email & other details from facebook javascript sdk

Tags: javascript, facebook

I need to login via facebook using javascript sdk and retrieve email id and general info of user.

Here is the my code. Please tell me where I'm going wrong:

```
 <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({ appId: 'your_app_id', status: true, cookie: true,
            xfbml: true
        });

        FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
            if (response.session) {
                greet();
            }
         });
    };
    (function () {
        var e = document.createElement('script');
        e.type = 'text/javascript';
        e.src = document.location.protocol +
      '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        e.async = true;
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    } ());

    function greet() {
        FB.api('/me', function (response) {
            alert('Welcome, ' + response.name + "!");
            alert('Your email id is : '+ response.email);
        }


        );
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the login part of getLoginStatus().  Without login, you cannot prompt the user with `email` permission.  Here's some helper code to get you pointed in the right direction.

```
    FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
        if (response.status=== 'connected') {
            greet();
        } else {
           FB.login(function(response){/*do something*/},{scope:'email`});
        }
     });
```

Also `response.session` is for the old oauth, not the new oauth2.  Please see:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/